# rails: how to update multiple records using "accepts_nested_attributes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Let's say I have a *cat* model and a *life* model. And let's say a cat (`@cat`) `has_many` lives, and a cat `accepts_nested_attributes for` a life.
Now, if I wanted to update 7 lives (`@lives`) at once, using one `form_for(@cat)`, how would that form look like? This is what I've tried, but in this form only the attributes for the last life are passed to the params hash:

```
  <%= form_for(@cat) do |f| %>
    <% @lives.each do |life| %>
      <%= f.fields_for(life) do |l| %>
        <%= l.input :date_of_birth, as: :date %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the attributes in your controller

```
@cat = Cat.find(<criteria>)
@cat.lives.build
```

In your example, you have a loop inside a loop.  Try this:

```
<%= form_for(@cat) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:lives) do |l| %>
    <%= l.input :date_of_birth, as: :date %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No go; my problem is not the controller action, but how to pass input "date_of_birth" for all 7 lives into the params hash. So I'd want to look the params hash like:

Comment: "cat"=>{"lives"=>{
                              {"life01"=>{"date_of_birth"=>"01-01-1950"}},
                              {"life02"=>{"date_of_birth"=>"01-01-1951"}},
                                 etcetc 
                               }

Comment: and then, in the (cat-)controller, loop through params[:cat][:lives], and update the lives.

Comment: The above code should do that.  What does the params hash look like with the code I gave?

Comment: Just a single life/date_of_birth:
`"cat"=>{"lives"=>{"date_of_birth"=>"01-01-1950"}}`

Comment: and it also render a single input-field, instead of 7

Comment: I updated what the controller should contain.  It really sounds like the controller is not building the association correctly.  What is the output of `@cat.lives.count`?    Also, check out [this](http://laptite.github.io/blog/2014/02/26/deep-nesting-with-has-many-through-and-a-join-model/)

Comment: thnx! you've really helped me! Actually the `@lives` I mentioned earlier are not ALL the lives associated with `@cat`. If I build the form, using `@cat.lives` (all associated lives), the form works!.

Comment: So that brings us to the next level: how to update/render fields_for not ALL, but only SOME lives, f.e. `lives.where(:realm => 'earth')`? I'll try to sort it out myself first.

Comment: My suggestion would be `@cat.lives.where(<criteria>).build`

Comment: No, that's in the controller. In the view, I only want form fields for certain lives: something like `<%= f.fields_for(:lives).where(:realm => 'earth') %>` ... but that too simple, I guess.

Comment: My original comment still stands, did you try it? If you specify a criteria before building, the only field that should show up are the ones that meet that criteria

Comment: But I don't want to build records, I want to update (certain) existing records?

Comment: Building will prepare them to be updated. If you don't want to show fields that don't match the criteria, use my method. if you want to show all the fields but only update certain ones after-the-fact, that requires iterating over params in the update method

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it to work:
In the cat-controller: `@cat.lives.where(:id => 6).build`.
In the view: `f.fields_for(:lives) do |l|`.
But this still renders all associated lives (instead of only life nr.6)?

Comment: Found a solution! ref. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder#object-instance_method

1. I created an instance variable `@lives` containing the lives I want to update/display
2. Then in the view this:
`<%= form_for(@cat) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:lives) do |l| %>'
    ** <%= l.input :date_of_birth, as: :date if @lives.include?(l.object) %> **
  '<% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>`
That will only display fields for lives in @lives! I'm so glad ((((-: The formbuilder .object method!! Never seen it before, but glad to have found it.